# Vector space Proof question linear independency

Tags: vector-spaces

Prove that if vectors $v_1,v_2...,v_k$ in a vector space V are linearly independent and a vector $u\in V$ is such that $u\notin \text{lin}(\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\})$,then the vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_k,u$ are linearly independent.

My attempt:

$u\notin \text{lin}(\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\})$ since clearly $u=0\cdot v_1...+0\cdot v_k+1\cdot u$
so $0\cdot v_1+...0\cdot v_k+u(1-1)=0$  , and given that $v_1,...v_k$ are linearly independent implies $\text{span}(\{v_1,...v_k,u\})=0$ if only if all real coefficient $=0$.

I guess my answer is wrong, any help
, thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what the statement "given that $v_1,...v_k$ are linearly independent implies span({$v_1,...v_k,u$})=0 if only if all real coefficient=0" is supposed to mean, but it makes no sense as written.

Comment: $a_i.v_i=0$ if only if $a_i=0$ for i=1,2...n.     so only way to get 0+b.u=0 is by b=0 aswell....

Comment: I think you have the right idea, but you should say it a bit more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good way to think about it.

Suppose The set $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_n, u\}$ form a linearly dependent set. Then one is a linear combination of the others - say,

$$ u = \sum_{j = 1}^n c_j v_j $$

and so $u \in \operatorname{Span} \{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$.

Thus the original statement holds.